# Does this reference cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, reference

I have a TabControl and each tab contains a TradeBookSetViewModel.  As the Tradebook can grow quite big, the user can remove the book if needed.

On a DeleteBook() I simply remove the the TradeBookSetViewModel from the observablecollection:

```
_bookSetViewModels.Remove(oldbook);
```

Then I create a new emptyBook as a placeholder and insert it in the same tab position. The Tab still looks as it was holding the tradeBook, but it actually is empty.

For that I resolve a new instance from the Unity Container and copy the DisplayName from the oldBook into the emptyBook.

```
BookSetViewModel emptyBook = _container.Resolve<BookSetViewModel>();
emptyBook.DisplayName = oldbook.DisplayName;
_bookSetViewModels.Insert(positionOfDisposedTab, emptyBook);
```

So far so good.

But later I realized the emptyBook requires also the Books property. The property Books is of type `Dictionary<string, CustomClassItem>` Hence I thought first I could do the same thing as I did with the DisplayName.

```
emptyBook.Books = oldbook.Books;
```

But couldn't that mean that the emptyBook would be referring to the oldBook and hence the oldBook can't be garbage collected any longer?

Maybe I should just clone the dictionary like this instead:

```
emptyBook.Books = book.Books.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

**Goal:** At the end of the day, I need the Books property in the emptyBook to be not null and yet the oldBook shall be able to be garbage collected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Pretty sure it would still be garbage collected, but the dictionary you're referring to wouldn't be collected since you're still using it.  You could put a destructor on the class and call GC.Collect() to see if the destructor gets called if you want to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But couldn't that mean that the emptyBook would be referring to the oldBook and hence the oldBook can't be garbage collected any longer?

No, not unless there's something else you haven't mentioned.

All you have here is two objects (`emptyBook` and `oldbook`) that *refer to* the same `Books` dictionary. That doesn't create any reference relationship between them; each has no way of knowing about the other.

So long as `oldbook` is not reachable from root through another reference, it will be eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no direct or indirect reference from your dictionary back to your view model class, then there is no problem.

emptyBook and oldBook will just both refer to the same dictionary, but outgoing references aren't stopping garbage collection, only incoming connections do so.

Answer (score 0):

In additon I would say consider that the "beauty" of `TabControl`, that user can work *always only with one Tab*. Consider to have one `View Model`, with multiple `Models` behind. Based on `Tab` selected always the same `View Model` picks from model's collection correct `Tradebook`. On `Tab selection changed` the `View Model` is assigned to a active tab.

Answer (score 0):

The `Book` and the dictionary that the book points to are two independent objects.  One just refers to the other.

Referring to a field or property of a class doesn't create a reference to the class that contains that field or property.

If you store a reference to `oldbook.DisplayName`, you are storing a reference to the dictionary object.  You are not storing a reference to the `Book` object that `oldbook` points to.

When the garbage collector runs, it will see that you are referencing the dictionary, and won't collect it.  It will see that you aren't referencing the `Book`, and will collect it.

This assumes of course that you aren't actually referencing the `Book` object anywhere else.  If no class has the object that `oldbook` referred to as a property or field, and you've removed it from any containers, or the container that hold the `Book` are no longer referenced, then it will be collected.